# If $f$ is entire, why is $g$ being defined this way: $g(z)=\begin{cases} \frac{f(z)-f(a)}{z-a} &z\ne a\\ f'(a) &z=a \end{cases} $

Tags: complex-analysis

In Complex Analysis by Bak & Newman, if $f$ is entire, $g$ is defined as: $g(z)=\begin{cases}
\frac{f(z)-f(a)}{z-a}  &z\ne a\\
f'(a) &z=a
\end{cases}
$

I don't understand why this is. Is $g$ the derivative of $f$? What is going on here?

[image]

Here is a screenshot of what is being said. **Why is $g$ being defined this way?** There is no motivation.

Comment: This is just some function; without context, there's not much that we can say about what $g$ is.... but it's not $f'$.

Comment: I think it is because $$\lim_{z \to a} \frac{f(z) - f(a)}{z - a} = f'(a)$$ if $f$ is entire. Now $\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{z - a}$ is holomorphic everywhere except at $a$. If $a$ is a [removable singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity), then defining in this way makes $g$ entire.

Comment: As a guess, the equation $f(z)=f(a)+(z-a)g(z)$ is a first step in the [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) of $f(z)$.

Answer (score 3):

No, $g$ is *not* the derivative of $f$. Nobody can tell you what is going on here unless you say in which context $g$ is being defined.

Comment: I have attached a screenshot

Comment: @AlJebr Read the rest of the chapter and you'll see $g$ being used to prove properties of $f$.

Comment: I see, but why is $g$ being defined this way to begin with?

Comment: @AlJebr Because it's useful, as Alex Vong's comment on the main post implies. But you really do need to just see how it's useful by reading the chapter.

Comment: I try, analysis just doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @AlJebr It is because entire functions are very nice, so you want to extend holomorphic function on a smaller domain to an entire function. Example of niceness of entire function: [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)): any bounded entire function is a constant. It can be used to prove the fundamental theorem of algebra, which gets me excited, since I enjoy more of the "algebra side" of maths...